# Competing methods for estimating autocorrelation time

Tags: python, autocorrelation, markov-chain-montecarlo

I'm testing several methods for obtaining the integrated autocorrelation time (IAT) of some synthetic data using Python. These methods are:

- emcee: the [built-in method](https://emcee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/autocorr/#computing-autocorrelation-times) in this MCMC package.
- ISE: *Initial sequence estimators* as defined in [Thompson (2010)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.0175) (with a criteria for selecting the number of lags taken from the [emcee docs](https://emcee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/autocorr/#computing-autocorrelation-times))
- BM: *Batch means* as defined in Thompson (2010).
- AR(p): *AR process* as defined in Thompson (2010).
- ACOR: an adapted version of the [Goodman](https://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/goodman/software/acor/) code.
- mESS: *Multivariate effective sample size* from [Vats et al. (2015)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.07713), converted into IAT dividing it by the sample size (ie: $IAT=N/mESS$)

The synthetic data is generated by simply adding some normal noise to a sine wave, with different values of the standard deviation $\sigma$ where a larger $\sigma$ means less correlated data:

[image]
$$\mathrm{(heavily\; correlated\; data\; with\; \sigma=0.1)}$$

[image]
$$\mathrm{(mostly\; uncorrelated\; data\; with\; \sigma=5)}$$

The result looks like this:

[image]

This looks reasonable as the IAT tends to converge to the expected minimum value of 1 for uncorrelated data for all methods. What I can not understand is that weird spike for the AR(p) method for low $\sigma$ values.

I use [statsmodels' Autoregressive AR(p) model](http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR.html) to obtain both the number of lags and the fitted coefficients needed to estimate the IAT following Eq (7) in Thompson (2010).

My question therefore is: is this behaviour for the AR(p) method expected, or should I be looking for some bug in my code?

---

*The Python code is a bit long so I don't paste it here. It can be found in [this repo](https://github.com/Gabriel-p/autocorrelation_times).*

Comment: I haven't had a chance to run your code, but I have been looking into some similar analysis and here are two observations: 150 model_fit = model.fit(ix='aic', trend='nc') I think you meant 'ic' here. 156 iat = (1. - np.dot(lags[:n_p], coeffs)) / (1. - np.sum(coeffs)) ** 2 76 lags = np.correlate(x, x, mode='full')[-x.size:] Based on my understanding of Thompson's paper, you should use lags[1:n_p+1].